# APIM policy expressions with array-driven XML elements

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Using [API Management Policy Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) is it possible to output a variable length array to a set of XML elements?

I'm using [Policy Fragments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policy-fragments) and [`<validate-jwt>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy) as an example, majority of our policies only require a single `<audience>`, but have some edge cases with multiples. Audiences doesn't support a `separator` attribute like `claim` and would prefer to avoid cloning fragments just to support a 2nd or 3rd audience.

Unfortunately I can't see how to implement a tidy razor-style foreach to build the XML (validation error: `Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 17, column 2: The element 'audiences' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'audience'.`) - arrived at the policy below which *works* but has enough of a code smell that there must be a cleaner way.

#### Messy POC example

```xml
<set-variable name="apiAudiences" value="api://abc api://def" />
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized">
    <audiences>
        <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid").Split(' ')[0])</audience>
        <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid").Split(' ')[1])</audience>
        <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid").Split(' ')[2])</audience>
        <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid").Split(' ')[3])</audience>
        <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid Invalid").Split(' ')[4])</audience>
    </audiences>
</validate-jwt>
```

Yes, this could be re-written using [choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/choose-policy), but cause more duplication at the fragment level and it wouldn't scale as well if multiple `validate-jwt` properties needed a variable number of results.

#### Fragment Example - ReusableJwtValidation

```xml
<fragment>
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid1 Invalid2 Invalid3").Trim().Split(' ')[0])</audience>
            <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid1 Invalid2 Invalid3").Trim().Split(' ')[1])</audience>
            <audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid1 Invalid2 Invalid3").Trim().Split(' ')[2])</audience>
        </audiences>
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="roles" match="any" separator=" ">
                <value>@((string)context.Variables["apiRoles"])</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="delete" />
</fragment>
```

#### Used in a API-Scoped Policy

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="apiAudiences" value="api://dummyGuid1 api://dummyGuid2" />
        <set-variable name="apiRoles" value="dev.DummyAPI.Read dev.DummyAPI.ReadWrite" />
        <include-fragment fragment-id="ReusableJwtValidation" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: How do you want to define the policy for audience?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I might be answering the wrong question here so feel free to nudge me in the right direction.

I'm flexible on the audience definition if I can use the same method for one, two or three - however as this will be inside a fragment;

a) the audiences will need to be defined in a way that supports being passed through from policy to fragment - why my example uses set-variable

b) we'll need to support similar definitions for claims and others, so if these all followed a common approach it would make the variable definition easier

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a sample policy as per your requirement

Comment: You can define <audience>You can directly pass the audience value here</audience>

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin have added fragment and policy examples -- I know I can pass audiences directly, but I want to try and pass a variable number of them as we have a number of APIs which don't follow the standard pattern and we'll likely run into this with another property as well so trying to see if there's a better way to do this than an array with dummy values tacked on.

Comment: Above given policy work for me `<audience>@((((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"]) + " Invalid1 Invalid2 Invalid3").Trim().Split(' ')[0])` also takes the individual audience from set-variable. Even you can try using `<claim name="aud" match="any" separator=" ">
    <value>@((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"])</value>
   </claim>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Audiences doesn't support a `separator` attribute like `claim` and would prefer to avoid cloning fragments just to support a 2nd or 3rd audience.

I have used your policy and it works for me. If you want to use `separator` for audiences, then you can use the below given policy.

***ReusableJwtValidation***-

```xml
<fragment>
    <validate-jwt  header-name="Authorization"  failed-validation-httpcode="401"  failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <openid-config  url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/2773f7fd-d343-4afe-8230-e735719f9b0b/.well-known/openid-configuration"  />
        <required-claims>
            <claim  name="aud"  match="any"  separator=" ">
                <value>@((string)context.Variables["apiAudiences"])</value>                         
            </claim>
            <claim  name="roles"  match="any"  separator=" ">
                <value>@((string)context.Variables["apiRoles"])</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
    <set-header  name="Authorization"  exists-action="delete"  />
</fragment>
```

***Output***-

[image]

[image]

If you want to iterate over multiples Audiences using choose or foreach loop specifically, then you can check with the Product team to get further information about its feasibility.